# Angular in Google Maps InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive

I may be asking the same question as [Similar q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226975/angularjs-ng-include-inside-of-google-maps-infowindow), but I'm not sure!

Basically I have code to add markers to a Google map. Then an infowindow displays.
How can I put a form in here that has elements binding to the scope of a module?
Angular is running ok on the rest of the page (I have a simple expressions to test this), but it's not running in the form as {{text}} never changes.

```
var html =
"<form id=\"markerInput\" ng-controller=\"markerCtrl\">"+
"<input ng-model=\"text\">{{text}}</form>";

infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    infowindow.setContent(html);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
});
```

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I recently come across this problem and had trouble finding relevant info so it can definately help somebody out there, I fixed it using .$apply to read more please visit this link http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: I am still not able to resolve the problem, do you have any demo code for this?

Comment: I have created a js object, did all the logic I need on the `click listener` and then used `apply` to force Angular to update, prob not very useful but below you can find parts of the code I used
`google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                Map.setMarker(marker.cleanTitle);
                Map.setPlace(marker.location);
                Map.loadMarker();
                $scope.$apply();
            });`