# AngularJS google maps infoWindow is not compiled

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-google-maps

I tried to implement google maps infoWindow using AngularJS.

I have a template `<div>{{foo}}<br/>`, with `$scope.foo="bar"`

I want to see the info window with the value "bar" instead of seeing "{{foo}}". Thus, I compiled and set the contents with it, but no luck yet.

Some may think this is duplicate to 
[AngularJS ng-include inside of Google Maps InfoWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226975/angularjs-ng-include-inside-of-google-maps-infowindow), but I want to compile contents dynamically.

Here is the code I have now, http://plnkr.co/edit/RLdAcaGz5FfmJEZi87ah?p=preview

```
  angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
    var mapOptions = { zoom: 4, center: myLatlng };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({position: myLatlng});

    var x = "<div>{{foo}}<br/>{{foo}}";
    $scope.foo="bar";
    var el = $compile(x)($scope);
    infowindow.setContent(el.html());
    infowindow.open(map);
  })
```

I was thinking `$scope.apply()`, but was not able to run in the code.

Is there a way to have google maps InfoWindow `$compile`d?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there!

You're right about needing to do a `$scope.$apply` to trigger parsing of template `x`, but since you're already in the middle of a digest cycle, calling `$scope.$apply` will give you a `$rootScope:inprog` error. You'll need to create a new digest cycle where you call `$scope.$apply`:

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function() {
  $scope.$apply();
  infowindow.setContent(el.html());
  infowindow.open(map);          
});
```

- [Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Ly0gHecMYyqRTgjhHz4?p=preview)
- [Difference between $timeout and $evalAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17303759/451480)