# AngularJS 1.3.X ng-include inside of Google Maps InfoWindow

Tags: angularjs

In angular 1.3.x (!) (for angular 1.0.x all fine).

I'm trying to include a template file '/test.html' as the content of my InfoWindow from service. (Original question is [AngularJS ng-include inside of Google Maps InfoWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226975/angularjs-ng-include-inside-of-google-maps-infowindow/30726988))

But code from original question page is not valid for AngularJS 1.3.15 (in my case minor version is 15).

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
```

You can test current bug with http://plnkr.co/edit/IkDzol?p=preview

Does anyone have any idea why?

Thanks.